# How to specify XSL attribute only for specific element in XML for a Filemaker extract

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, filemaker

I'm trying to build an xml file from data in a Filemaker database. The basic structure of the XML using a XSL is ok but I am having one issue with adding an attribute only for a specific element. The matchmode="0" should only be applied to the "ref" element and not the "date".

**This is the XML I get:**

```
    <root>
    <transportbookings>
    <transportbooking>
    <ref matchmode="0">260458</ref>          *! ok*
    <date matchmode="0">13-6-2023</date>     *! not ok*
    </transportbooking>
    </transportbookings>
    </root>
```

**This is the XLS I created:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fm="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult" exclude-result-prefixes="fm">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="rename">
    <item from="reference" to="ref" />
    <item from="pu_date" to="date" />
   </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="fm:ROW"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="fm:ROW">
    <transportbookings>
      <transportbooking>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="fm:reference | fm:pu_date" mode="rename" />
        </transportbooking>
    </transportbookings>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="rename">
    <xsl:element name="{document('')//xsl:variable[@name = 'rename']/item[@from = local-name(current())]/@to}">

           <xsl:attribute name="matchmode">0</xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`
```

**This is what need to have:**

```
    <root>
    <transportbookings>
    <transportbooking>
    <ref matchmode="0">260458</ref>
    <date>13-6-2023</date>   **! NO MATCHMODE**
    </transportbooking>
    </transportbookings>
    </root>
```

I tried an if statement but I could not get it to work. I think I'm making it to complex or ?

**This is the RAW XML.**

0 DTS.fmp12 DTS_XML  122 260458 <pu_date>13-6-2023</pu_date>

Comment: Please edit your question and add the raw XML output you get by exporting as XML with no XSL transformation.

Comment: <FMPDSORESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
<ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
<DATABASE>DTS.fmp12</DATABASE>
<LAYOUT>DTS_XML</LAYOUT>
<ROW MODID="3" RECORDID="172">
<Id>122</Id>
<reference>260458</reference>
<pu_date>13-6-2023</pu_date>
</ROW>
</FMPDSORESULT>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fm="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult" 
exclude-result-prefixes="fm">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/FMPDSORESULT">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="fm:ROW"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fm:ROW">
    <transportbookings>
        <transportbooking>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="fm:reference | fm:pu_date"/>
        </transportbooking>
    </transportbookings>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fm:reference ">
    <ref matchmode="0">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </ref>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fm:pu_date" ">
    <date>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </date>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But you gave us no input to test with. Note also that this creates `transportbookings` wrapper for each exported record. If - as it would seem from your example - you are exporting only one record, then this could be much shorter.

I would also suggest you consider using the `FMPXMLRESULT` grammar for your export. This will protect your stylesheet against changes to field names.

Comment: Michael thanks a lot! This pointed me in the correct direction. There are actually more records, but I simplified the example. I got it working now.